# Distributed tensorflow with external client

Tags: tensorflow

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py

I run this tensorflow code in client below architecture.

[image: Cluster Architecture]

Every ps and worker servers just run the tensorflow server and join.

Two processes will run on the client instance. One requests work to worker0, and the other requests work to worker1.

I run the code with arguments like this.

```
# ./mnist_replica.py --task_index=0 --num_gpus=0 --existing_servers=True \
  --ps_hosts="10.0.0.36:9999,10.0.0.37:9999" \
  --worker_hosts="10.0.0.38:9999,10.0.0.39:9999" \
  --job_name="worker" \
  --train_step=1000000    

# ./mnist_replica.py --task_index=1 --num_gpus=0 --existing_servers=True \
  --ps_hosts="10.0.0.36:9999,10.0.0.37:9999" \
  --worker_hosts="10.0.0.38:9999,10.0.0.39:9999" \
  --job_name="worker" \
  --train_step=1000000
```

Finally, this is the resource usage by each instance since I run the above command.

[image]

The biggest difference from the tensorflow distributed learning tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) is the existing_server option. In the tutorial, you run a task for each worker, but in my environment, the task is run from an external client.

My questions are these.

1. If you look at the network usage of the client instance, you can see that tx is very high. Why is the client's tx so high? And what kind of data is sent by the client?
2. I checked the packets I care about transferring what kind of data the client is sending. Because it is binary data, I can't understand exactly. However, I see the string 'placeholder' for the packet with the highest percentage of transmission. If this is for input data, why it send input data every time and use network a lot?
3. Is there a way to reduce the client's network traffic?

Thank you.